# Resizing ToolStripButtons to fit complete BackGround image

Tags: .net, image, winforms, toolstripbutton

My goal is totally fit image in toolStripButton and toolStripDropDownButton.

If a image in the button set with image property, I can not totally fit the image in the button. Because of margin, border, or something of the button.(I don't know exactly).

So I try to set the image in the button with BackgroudImage property. After I adjust some property(like AutoSize, Size and so on...), I can fit image in button.

but in this case, I can not see background image. It is disappear, when the mouse cursor is located in the button.

How can I solve this problem??

Image Property. I can not remove the gap between images.
[image]

BackgroundImage Property. I can not see the image, when mouse cursor is on the image.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you found out why it leaves a space around the Image property.  You can customize the rendering of the button by assigning the ToolStrip.Renderer property.  That could look something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        toolStrip1.Renderer = new MyRenderer();
    }
    private class MyRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer {
        protected override void OnRenderButtonBackground(ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs e) {
            if (e.Item.BackgroundImage == null) base.OnRenderButtonBackground(e);
            else {
                Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, e.Item.Size);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(e.Item.BackgroundImage, bounds);
                if (e.Item.Pressed) {
                    // Something...
                }
                else if (e.Item.Selected) {
                    // Something...
                }
                using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black)) {
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, bounds.X, bounds.Y, bounds.Width - 1, bounds.Height - 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

You'll have to fill in the // Something... lines and do some kind of drawing that makes it obvious to the user that the button is pressed or selected.  Maybe draw a rectangle with a thick Pen, it is up to you.

Comment: Wow. Amazing. it's new world. :) thanks a lot. this response is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

When you display an image in the background of a ToolStripButton, moving the mouse over it will cause it to disappear, by design.  The MouseOver effect of the ToolStripButton is drawn on top of any background image, otherwise the effect would never be seen.

When you are setting the Image property of the ToolStripButton, make sure that the ImageScaling is set 'None' to guarantee that the AutoSizing feature scales up the ToolStripButton to fit the image size.

The 'gap between the images' is designed into the ToolStrip object so that the user knows where one button ends and the other begins.

Comment: hmm.. I didn't know about the cause, before reading your response.
I will study more. thanks Stewbob. :)