# Resizing ToolStrip item's image

Tags: vb.net, image, winforms, toolstripbutton

Is there any way I can fit/resize the image of ToolStrip item? I already set the property `AutoSize = False` , `ImageScaling = SizeToFit` & `Size = 40, 40` but only the item's boxes resizing (leave spaces around image) and the image size is still with it's default size.

I then came up with inserting the image using BackgroundImage instead of inserting it at Image. I can fit/resize the image but the problem is when I run my system and pointing the cursor on the ToolStrip item, the item's image disappear. I found this solution [Resizing ToolStripButtons to fit complete BackGround image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495782/resizing-toolstripbuttons-to-fit-complete-background-image) but I don't know how to apply it using `vb.net`

Kindly to help me. Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to use `BackGroundImage` property. Just use `Image` and Use `ImageScaling` property of `ToolStripItem` and `ImageScalingSize` of `ToolStrip` to control size of item as I did in the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If you want your images show in original size**

- Set `AutoSize` property of `ToolStrip` to `true`
- Set `ImageScaling` property of `ToolStripItem` to `None`

**If you want your images show in a specific size**

- Set `AutoSize` property of `ToolStrip` to `true`
- Set `ImageScalingSize` property of `ToolStrip` to your specific size, for example `32,32`
- Set `ImageScaling` property of `ToolStripItem` to `SizeToFit`

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will help

```
Partial Public Class Form1
    Inherits Form
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        'using new render instead of def render
        toolStrip1.Renderer = New MyRenderer()
    End Sub
    Private Class MyRenderer
        'apply everything of default render
        Inherits ToolStripProfessionalRenderer

        'this will override the Render Butoon Bg event
        Protected Overrides Sub OnRenderButtonBackground(e As ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs)
            'if image is nothing then use the def render
            If e.Item.BackgroundImage Is Nothing Then
                MyBase.OnRenderButtonBackground(e)
            Else

                'redraw the image to fit the area
                Dim bounds As New Rectangle(Point.Empty, e.Item.Size)
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(e.Item.BackgroundImage, bounds)
                ' Something...
                If e.Item.Pressed Then
                    ' Something...
                ElseIf e.Item.Selected Then
                End If

                'draw the fit button here
                Using pen As New Pen(Color.Black)
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, bounds.X, bounds.Y, bounds.Width - 1, bounds.Height - 1)
                End Using
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

Comment: A good answer would go into *slightly* more detail on how a piece of uncommented code would help